# Force UITableView or UICollectionView to load cell on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

From the question the answer seems just `reloadData`. 
This method starts the process that makes the tableview reload data from tableview from `numberOfSections` to `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`. 
The fact is that most of those methods are launched probably in the next runloop or `CATransaction`.
I'm trying to get the full size of the tableview to show all the cells thus avoiding the need of scrolling.
The tableView knows its content size only when it load the heightForRowAtIndexPath or the cells, so it seems to impossible to ask the table view for its `contentSize` right after `-reloadData`.
It seems useless also to invalidate its intrinsic content size and force auto layout, or asking a -`sizeToFit` until it loads all the cells it doesn't know its size. Tried also with `+systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:`giving `UILayoutFittingExpandedSize` with no success.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I've got a big vertical scroll view, with some normal views as subviews, since I need to add more views in a way that is totally like a tableview, I'm trying to calculate the table view height and change the scroll view content size accordingly. The TV should not scroll so I must know its content size.

Comment: Query your data source yourself and find things out like cell size?

Comment: It's what I'm doing now.. but when we talk about TV we should think that in a gereal case they could have variable height, header, footer etc

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of table and collection views is that you do **not** have to load all the data at once but recycle the UI elements and only load what is visible. That is the purpose of the `datasource` approach.

To add an item at the end, just change your data source to have one more that is returned from `numberOfRowsInSection` or `numberOfItemsInSection`. Make sure your data source also has content to populate this data point.

You can then `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:`, `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:` `reloadSections:` etc. methods of the datasource protocols to reload these data points, but if they are not visible that might not even be necessary.

If, on the other hand, you have a custom `UIScrollView`, your data source should have the heights or widths of your cells / subviews. You can then easily calculate the position of any new subview to be added.

Comment: Thx Mundi, I understand you point, but this is not exactly what I was asking. Even if I need to use 1 element the contentSize of the tv is unknown until it loads the cells

Comment: What do you need the contentSize for? Why would you care?

Comment: Because I need to know the height at which the TV can display all the possible TVC. Performance is not an issue since it won't display more that 10 elements

Comment: Why do you need to know the height? Where is the problem in just adding all the heights somewhere?

Comment: Well Mundi, but the overall picture is kind of big (I've inherited this project) and I can't explain why I am doing that (but is due to the context), also because I won't add any useful clue to the problem unfortunately.  The fact is that I need to know the content size of the TV and I'm already approaching the problem calculating the height in another way, but is really not a very general solution. So the question is: since TV doesn't update the contentSize right after calling reloadData is there a way to force that process?

Comment: Then the simple answer is "no". You need to calculate the height from a different source. Look into your implementation of `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and take it from there, loading potentially missing information explicitly without the table view data source methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the right content size of your tableView, than you can calculate it yourself using `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. 
E.g. if cell's height is static, i.e. its never changes, then just simply multiply number of your rows with that height. Else, if you cell's height is dynamic, then you can do following:

```
- (CGSize)tableViewContentSize
{
    CGFloat contentHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < numberOfRows; k++) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:k inSection:i];
            contentHeight += [self tableView:self.tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
    }

    CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width, contentHeight);
    return contentSize;
}
```

Comment: Thx, but as written in the comments above is exactly what I'm doing now